# No Test Ads Showing on Android -AdMob

Tags: android, react-native, admob, firebase-admob

I have updated firebase/admob package.

Interstitial ads are showing but banners are not.

Before update the package, also banner ads were fine.

Version:

```
"@react-native-firebase/admob": "^7.6.9"
```

UnitID:

```
const adUnitIdBanner = __DEV__
? TestIds.BANNER
: Platform.OS === 'ios'
? 'xxx'
: 'yyy'
```

BannerAd:

```
<BannerAd
   unitId={adUnitIdBanner}
   size={BannerAdSize.SMART_BANNER}
   onAdLoaded={() => {
     console.log('Advert loaded');
   }}
   onAdFailedToLoad={(result) => {
     console.log('result', result)
     console.log('Ad failed to load', arguments)
   }}
 />
```

Ad Load Fail Log:

```
result [Error: [admob/error-code-no-fill] The ad request was successful, but no ad was   
returned due to lack of ad inventory.]
LOG  Ad failed to load [[Object], [Function metroRequire], [Function metroImportDefault], 
[Function metroImportAll], {"exports": {"default": [Function MainScreen]}, "hot": 
{"_acceptCallback": null, "_didAccept": false, "_disposeCallback": null, "accept": [Function 
accept], "dispose": [Function dispose]}, "id": 1034}...
```

Logcat:

```
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class io.invertase.firebase.admob.ReactNativeFirebaseAdMobBannerAdViewManager
```

Everything is fine on iOS.

What could be the reason that no Banner Test Ads are showing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to `SMART_BANNER`.

I changed it to `BANNER`, now ad showing up.

Fail Log misleading because there should not be `inventory` for the `TEST ADS` I think.

Also for the test ads:

Production ads showing up written `Test Ad` on it.